# Get HTML from local HTML file using selenium chrome webdriver in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to open the local HTML file using selenium webdriver (Chrome) and this is my try

```
Sub Test()
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim bot  As New ChromeDriver

bot.Start "Chrome", "about:blank"
bot.Get "file:///C:\Sample.html"

Set html = bot.getHtmlSource
End Sub
```

I got an error at the last line `Set html = bot.getHtmlSource` which is `Object doesn't support this property or method`
So I am trying to get the HTML from the local HTML file.
Thanks advanced for the help.

Comment: Why not just to load the file content using FSO or ADODB.Stream?

Comment: @omegastripes I thought there is a way using webdriver to get the HTML directly. So I posted the question